# Replacement for deprecated Google web search API for Android

Tags: android

I'm looking to search Google from my Android app and return results. Everything I've found points towards the Google Web Search API which the page now says [is deprecated](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html#_fonje_local) and is being replaced by a [Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).

The new custom search API only allows you to search through websites you've created a custom search engine for. I want to search all of the internet as anyone would through Google.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has a *lot* of search capabilities - all built-in.

Look here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

Google Code and the Android SDK are two different things.  The Web Search API is Google Code and, and you noted, it has indeed been deprecated in favor of Google Custom Search:

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

http://www.google.com/cse/

Finally, here's a good blog entry that shows you how to invoke a Bing/Yahoo! web search from Android:

http://www.codexperiments.com/java/2011/01/create-your-own-web-search-application/

Frankly, the Bing API looks a heck of a lot better than Google Custom Search.  Starting with the fact that Bing's API doesn't limit you to 100 queries/day like Custom Search does :)

'Hope that helps!

Comment: Would i be able to use those to return the search results to my application so that i can display them whatever way i want?

Answer (score 0):

You can Bing search API -

First you need to create an account at Microsoft and get an account key, then use it as follows:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

/**
 * Created by Asaf on 08/06/2014.
 */
public class SearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            String bingUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?Query=%27pinhassi%27";

            String accountKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
            String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);

            URL url = null;
            url = new URL(bingUrl);

            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);
            InputStream response = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            String res = readStream(response);
            Log.d(TAG, res);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(line);
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```